# Align boxes with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I would like to remove the white space between "Box 1" and "Box 3."  Using "below=0cm and of box1" works to remove the white space below "Box 1" but "right=0cm and of box1" does *not* remove the white space to the right.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzstyle{Box} = [draw=black, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=3.75cm]
\node [name=box1, Box] {Box 1.};
\node [name=box2, below=0cm and of box1, Box] {Box 2.};
\node [name=box3, right=0cm and of box1, Box] {Box 3.};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove the `and`s in the specifications for `below` and `right`.

Also, the boxes can be shifted by the line width to avoid the appearance of thicker lines between the boxes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzstyle{Box} = [draw=black, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=3.75cm]
\node [name=box1, Box] {Box 1.};
\node [name=box2, below=-\pgflinewidth of box1, Box] {Box 2.};
\node [name=box3, right=-\pgflinewidth of box1, Box] {Box 3.};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The keyword `and` is only supported for the two-part directions `above left`, `below left`, `above right`, and `below right`.

Comment: Great...however I can not figure out how to re-work this so that one line is drawn between each box instead of sandwiching adjacent boxes which gives visibly thicker internal lines.

Comment: @v.walter See updated answer.